# Getting minimatch issue at the time of installing ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed nodejs version 7.3.0 after that I am trying to install ionic by CLI but I am getting below error :

> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

After exploring I got 2 answers from stack to `run npm update minimatch` and `npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2` but the issue is not getting resolved.

But after that it stops automatically.

So please help in solving this issue.

Comment: it's just a warn .. not an error i think

Answer (score -1):

```
    npm install -g minimatch uuid ionic
```